# Spark dataset - referring to column with type array w/ callUDF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

my data's schema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- dt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- myarr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

entryPage: Unit = ()
```

"myarr" is a Seq of size 2 constantly.

I'm trying to refer to the elements of this array inside a udf call:

```
filter(callUDF("size", $"myarr[0]") > 0 && callUDF("size", $"myarr[1]") > 0)
```

but I'm getting the below exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`myarr[0]`' given input columns: [dt, myarr];;
'Filter (('size('myarr[0]) > 0) && ('size('myarr[1]) > 0))
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: It does work like this BTW `.filter("size(myarr[0]) > 0 AND size(myarr[1]) > 0")`

Comment: Try using `$"myarr"(0)` to get the element. If you write `$"myarr[0]"` Spark will look for a column with that exact name, including the `[0]` part.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 filter(size($"myarr"(0)) > 0 && size($"myarr"(1)) > 0)
```

- And I also found out that I can use size(..) instead of callUDF("size",...)